# How to catch error Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, error-handling

In my Laravel app i try to open the URL ?q=test%0D%0A%0D%0Atest and get an error **Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected**

How can i catch this error so my app will not crush?

```
ErrorException:
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

  at /home/site/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:342
  at Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected', '/home/site/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php', 342)
     (/home/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:266)
  at Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}(2, 'Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected', '/home/site/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php', 342)
  at header('Location: http://local.promkod.ru?q=test

test', false, 301)
     (/home/site/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:342)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->sendHeaders()
     (/home/site/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:376)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->send()
     (/home/site/public/index.php:26)
```

Comment: You'll probably have to find what's causing the Location redirect and fix it there.

Comment: what do you think these are the encoded version of: `%0D%0A%0D%0A` ?

Comment: its 2 new lines - "/r/n/r/n"